# React api router can't show data in detail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, router

Im learning React with routing and api calls at the moment. I've got an api were I need to find all the urls and post them on a page that was successful. But now I need to make a detail page where I can show more information about the url. Page 1 is like : gather all the urls and show them in a list. And page 2 is if you have clicked on a url in the list on page 1 you will be navigated to page 2 where a detail dialog is showed.
I have the page 1 completely and I can navigate to page 2 but I can't show any data from the api in page 2 information/detailpage.I don't know how to work with the key and get the info. I Tried several things but none of them works. Im using link.Link as key and I need description property , url , api name.

**This is my page 1:**

```
import React from "react";
import {Link, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Detail } from './Detail';

export default class FetchLinks extends React.Component {
    state = {
        loading: true,
        links: [],
    };
    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "https://api.publicapis.org/entries?category=development";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({links: data.entries, loading: false});
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <div>loading...</div>
        }
        if (!this.state.links.length) {
            return <div>geen links gevonden</div>
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.links.map(link => (
                    <div key={link.Link}>
                        <ul><li>
                            <p>
                                <NavLink to={`/Detail/${link.Link}`}>
                                    {link.Link}
                                </NavLink>
                            </p>
                        </li></ul>
                    </div>))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**this is page 2:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Content from './Content';

const Detail = () =>{
return(
    <div>
        <h1>Detail Page</h1>
        <p>{this.state.links.Link}</p>
    </div>
)


}
export default Detail();
```

[This is how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiSNB.png)

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood correctly, you have all your data in page 1 and need to pass the data to page 2. For this you have to write your NavLink like this:

```
 <NavLink to={{
    pathname: `/Detail/${link.Link}`,
    state: link.Link
 }}>
    {link.Link}
 </NavLink>
```

Now you can use UseLocation hook of react-router to access this state that you just passed. So in page 2:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
    
    const Detail = () =>{
       const location = useLocation();         

       return (
          <div>
             <h1>Detail Page</h1>
             <p>{location.state.link}</p>
          </div>
       );

    }

    export default Detail();
```

You can read more about react-router hooks [here](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/).

Comment: I get many errors with useLocation

Comment: Do you have a routing component? Your FetchLinks and Detail component must be in a Switch (react-router-dom version 5 and lower) or Routes (react-router-dom version 6) component.

Comment: yes I do in my .app both pages in switch with their own routes